# How to migrate Android SqLite database from internal storage to Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have application which has Sqlite database file with version 1. Which was created using **SqliteOpenHelper** class.

Now I want to migrate old database to room database.

Below is my code and it seems not working for me.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Provides
AppDatabase provideDatabase(Application application) {
    String dbPath = "";
    if (application.getExternalFilesDir(null) != null) {
        dbPath = application.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
    } else {
        dbPath = application.getFilesDir().getPath();
    }

    return Room.databaseBuilder(application, AppDatabase.class, dbPath + File.separator + DB_NAME)
            .addMigrations(RoomDatabaseMigrationProvider.MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build();
}
```

Above code is not calling **RoomDatabaseMigrationProvider.MIGRATION_1_2**. I also tried adding a **RoomDatabase.Callback**. It is returning 0 in `void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db)` rather than version 1 and in `void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db)` method its returning version 2.

Below is my AppDatabase.java and Migration class

```
@Database(entities = {Calendar.class, Contest.class},
    version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ContestDao provideContestDao();

    public abstract CalanderDao provideCalanderDao();

}

public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {

    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull final SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        Log.d("##### Migration", "started....");
        migrateDatabase(database);
        Log.d("##### Migration", "completed....");
    }
};
```

Comment: You should first check if the database file is there where you expect it to be. The paths you try to use look wrong to begin with. Please tell full path used now.

Comment: The database file is present and app is working with same database file using room but for newly added columns and tables its throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   @Database(entities = {<all entity classes>}, 
              version = <incremented_sqlite_version>)
    public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        private static UsersDatabase INSTANCE;
        static final Migration      MIGRATION_<sqlite_version>_<incremented_sqlite_version> 
    = new Migration(<sqlite_version>, <incremented_sqlite_version>) {
             @Override public void migrate(
                        SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
               // Since we didn’t alter the table, there’s nothing else 
               // to do here.
             }
        };
```

For reference:

https://medium.com/google-developers/incrementally-migrate-from-sqlite-to-room-66c2f655b377

Comment: Thanks for reply. I followed the same link and its not working.

Comment: Go through this link for better understanding
https://thetechguru.in/migrating-sqlite-implementation-room/

Comment: you can follow the official page as well 

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Answer (score 0):

The migration was not working due to its **PRAGMA user_version**.

I was created a SQLite database using SQLite browser software and by default it sets 0 as **user_version**.

That's why I was getting **0** in `void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db)` method.

Below is my code that I used to solve this problem.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Provides
AppDatabase provideDatabase(Application application) {
    String dbPath;
    if (application.getExternalFilesDir(null) != null) {
        dbPath = application.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
    } else {
        dbPath = application.getFilesDir().getPath();
    }
    dbPath = dbPath + File.separator + DB_NAME;

    try { 
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteHelper.getSqliteHelper(application).getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.getVersion() == 0) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = 1");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Room.databaseBuilder(application, AppDatabase.class, dbPath)
            .addMigrations(RoomDatabaseMigrationProvider.MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build();
}
```